# Performance problems in apache server with php

Tags: php, xml, apache, httpservice

I think I have a performance problem in my apache server.
I have apache server on solaris 10 with php and some flash client applications.
The clients get data from server in XML formation with HTTPService requests.
sometimes the data doesn't arrive and sometimes it does.
maybe performance in the apache server or in the php (maybe its configurable in the php.ini file )
It's a serious problem for me. Please help me.
Best regards.
Elad.

php.ini Config file:

```
[PHP]
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
memory_limit = 512M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)
default_socket_timeout = 180000
; Enable the PHP scripting language engine under Apache.
engine = On
safe_mode = Off

; include_path=/opt/coolstack/php5/lib/php:.:
include_path=/opt/OV/httpd/php5/lib/php:.:
; extension_dir=/opt/coolstack/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613
extension_dir=/opt/OV/httpd/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613
; CSKmysql32 is required for mysql and mysqli extensions.
extension="mysql.so"
extension="mysqli.so"
extension="apc.so"
extension="zlib.so"
extension=dom.so

;extension=bcmath.so
;extension=bz2.so
;extension=calendar.so
;extension=ctype.so
;extension=dbase.so
;extension=dtrace.so
;extension=exif.so
;extension=ftp.so
;extension=hash.so
;extension=iconv.so
;extension=imap.so
;extension=json.so
extension=ldap.so
;extension=mbstring.so
;extension=openssl.so
;extension=pcntl.so
;extension=pdo_pgsql.so
;extension=pgsql.so
;extension=posix.so
;extension=pspell.so
;extension=shmop.so
;extension=snmp.so
;extension=soap.so
;extension=sockets.so
;extension=sysvmsg.so
;extension=sysvsem.so
;extension=sysvshm.so
;extension=tokenizer.so
;extension=wddx.so
;extension=xmlreader.so
;extension=xmlwriter.so
;extension=xsl.so
;extension=zip.so
;extension=memcache.so
;extension=tcpwrap.so
;zend_extension="/opt/coolstack/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/xdebug.so"
; hardened-php - uncomment to enable. See http://hardened-php.net
;extension="suhosin.so"


; CSKlibs package is required for following extensions :
extension=curl.so
;extension=dba.so
;extension=gd.so
;extension=gettext.so
;extension=gmp.so
;extension=tidy.so
;extension=odbc.so
;extension=pdo_odbc.so

; CSKtds is required for following extensions :
;extension=pdo_dblib.so

; CSKncurses is required for following extensions :
;extension=ncurses.so
;extension=readline.so

; CSKmysql32 package is required for following extensions :
;extension=pdo_mysql.so

; CSKapache2 package is required for following extensions :
;extension=xmlrpc.so

apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.optimization=0
apc.shm_size=128
apc.ttl=120
apc.user_ttl=120
apc.gc_ttl=120
apc.stat=1
apc.num_files_hint=1024
apc.user_entries_hint=100
apc.mmap_file_mask=/dev/zero
;apc.enable_cli=1

; Allow or prevent persistent links.
;mysql.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
;mysql.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
;mysql.max_links = -1

[Session]
session.use_cookies = 1
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor     = 5000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 6000
session.entropy_file = "/dev/urandom"
;session.cache_expire = 300
;session.cache_limiter = nocache
;session.save_path = "5;/tmp"
```

PHP Service script code for example:

```
class client
 {
    var $clientIP;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->clientIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    public function get_client_info()
    {
        print "<clientIP>".$this->clientIP."</clientIP>\n";

    }
}
```

Comment: We're going to either need to see some code or you're going to need to describe your configuration more thoroughly.

Comment: Posting the config file would be useful I suppose

Comment: I added the php.ini config file and code sample.
thanks.

Comment: Create a single PHP script that just echos the expected output to test.  If that works reliably, it's probably a code problem than configuration (fatal white-page-of-death error, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a problem with the actual server? Is it hitting swap heavily? lots of IO wait? cpu maxed out?

Or is it just the Apache service that is having issues, while everything else is running fine?

If it's the first case I would start by turning off Apache access logs in the httpd.conf file. That would reduce your IO by a lot, and would give the cpu time to deal with other stuff. Side effect of doing this is that some statistics scripts won't work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I realize that the problem is not the server itself but is probably in my Flash client application.
I'll post a proper question about it.
thank you for the help.
Regards.
Elad.